# steering behaviors collision avoidance: vehicle shaking before arrive at destination

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, ai, collision-avoidance

I have made a test sketch of collision avoidance using javascript, as you can see [right here](https://editor.p5js.org/italoricardogeske/sketches/LQfuOHhQd).

I want the vehicle to move to the clicked location, avoiding obstacles on the way. It is working, but not like I expected. When I am next to the obstacle and click on the opposite side of it, the vehicle shakes a little bit before arriving in the other side.

[image: illustration]

I am using [this tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-collision-avoidance--gamedev-7777) as base to my sketch, but cant find out the reason for this issue.

Here is my avoidance logic:

```
let centerPos = p5.Vector.add(this.position, createVector(10, 10));
  
let velocity = p5.Vector.sub(this.destination, centerPos);
let nVelocity = p5.Vector.normalize(velocity);
let seeAhead = p5.Vector.mult(nVelocity, SEE_AHEAD);
let ahead = p5.Vector.add(centerPos, seeAhead);
if (euclideanDistance(ahead, obs) <= obs.radius) {
  let avoidanceForce = p5.Vector.sub(ahead, obs.position);
  avoidanceForce.normalize().mult(MAX_AVOID_FORCE);
  this.movePosition.add(avoidanceForce);
} else if (euclideanDistance(centerPos, obs) <= obs.radius * 2) {
  let avoidanceForce = p5.Vector.sub(centerPos, obs.position);
  avoidanceForce.normalize().mult(MAX_AVOID_FORCE * 0.5);
  this.movePosition.add(avoidanceForce);
}
```

Here is my variables descriptions:

1. `centerPosition`: Vehicle center position
2. `velocity`: Distance between initial point and destination
3. `seeAhead`: n frames in the future
4. `ahead`: future new position

After calculating the vars above, check if the `ahead` vector is inside obstacle range or vehicle vector position is colliding with obstacle. If someone of these two conditions is true, apply avoid force.

I just want the vehicle to stop shaking when clicking at the opposite side of obstacle (see picture). Is it possible? I don't think this collision avoidance algorithm is working properly.

Comment: If you don't want to code it yourself, I would recommend looking into frameworks/plugins, like this one https://github.com/mikewesthad/navmesh

Comment: Programming realistic collisions/avoidance is educational but also very time consuming. When building an actual game you might want to look at a physics library: https://brm.io/matter-js/ .  Or when you use the ExcaliburJS game library, you can just switch it on with `physics = true`!!